# Dos submit a Edit y a Insert en el mismo Form

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, formularios

Este es mi formulario :

```
<form name='form_update' method='post' id="registerUser" action='update.php'>

<input type='text' class='form-control' name='nombre' value=<?=$nombre; ?> />
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='ne' value=<?=$ne; ?> />

<input type='submit' value='Guardar Edición' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='confirmation' data-title='Proceeder con esta Acción?' />

</form>
```

Como puedo agregar un segundo submit que me envié a una segunda dirección algo como `action='insert.php'`

La intención es que al terminar de editar algunos datos tal como aparecen en un formulario y esté satisfecho con esos cambios pueda tener un botón junto al update para guardar la información en una segunda tabla.

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: Hola Alan, a pasado por mi mente pero teniendo tantos cambios todo el tiempo de ultima hora yo preferiria limitar el numero de lenguajes al minimo y ya que quede la base hacer el upgrade a frameworks ajax y otros, pero gracias por tu sujerencia

Comment: Otra opcion es que unifiques los archivos `update.php` e `insert.php` que deberian de tener funcionalidades similares.  En ese caso podrias agregar otro `<input type='submit'>` y verificar en ese archivo de que boton viene la peticion.

Comment: en realidad es muy buena idea , algo como `<input a type='submit'>` y `<input b type='submit'>` y en mi update reconosca si es A haga el update y si es B haga el insert. podrias darme un ejemplo donde pueda ver como es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes unificar tu codigo en un solo archivo y tener dos botones `submit`.  El HTML quedaria de esta manera:

```
<form name='form_update' method='post' id="registerUser" action='update.php'>

<input type='text' class='form-control' name='nombre' value=<?=$nombre; ?> />
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='ne' value=<?=$ne; ?> />

<input type='submit' name="guardar" value='Guardar Edición' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='confirmation' data-title='Proceeder con esta Acción?' />
<input type='submit' name="insertar" value='Insertar Edición' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='confirmation' data-title='Proceeder con esta Acción?' />

</form>
```

Y luego en tu archivo PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['guardar']) {
    /* Aqui harias el update */
}
if (isset($_POST['insertar']) {
    /* Aqui harias el insert */
}
```

Comment: es un gran aporte y te agradesco mucho (creo que esta mal poner comentarios de agradecimiento pero no queria dejarlo sin reconocer el gran aporte que as echo)

Comment: De nada @claus. Y si tienes razon, la recomendacion es que en lugar de poner comentarios de agradecimiento aceptes las respuestas que te han ayudado.  Veo que has hecho varias preguntas pero no has aceptado ninguna respuesta.  Tenlo en cuenta para que la comunidad te siga apoyando.